# jquery validation error in Asp.net MVC - unable to get value of property 'call' : object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to do some validation checks on the client side but my ASP.NET MVC application fails even before opening the index page. I get the error Microsoft Jscript runtime error: unable to get value of the property 'call':object is null or undefined.

Below is my script. I'm using partial views to show a UI dialog to edit the employees. I've made sure that the jqueryval bundle is added to the _Layout.cshtml and clientsidevalidation is set true. any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks

```
var $form = $("#updateEmployeeForm");
$form.unbind();
$form.data("validator", null);
// Check document for changes
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
// Re add validation with changes
$form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
dialogDiv.dialog('open');
```

**partial view**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditEmployee", "Employee", new AjaxOptions
{
  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
  HttpMethod = "POST",
  OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
}, new { @id = "updateEmployeeForm" }))

{

  @Html.ValidationSummary(true) .....}
```

**My viewModel**

```
[Required]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string MiddleName { get; set;}
[Required]
```

Comment: I believe i have seen this when using jquery > 1.9 with asp.net mvc.  try installing jquery 1.8.2 and see if that solves it.  i think there is an issue with the unobtrusive ajax or validator with the new version of jquery

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to  Slicksim

"I believe i have seen this when using jquery > 1.9 with asp.net mvc. try installing jquery 1.8.2 and see if that solves it. i think there is an issue with the unobtrusive ajax or validator with the new version of jquery – Slicksim Apr 2 at 10:30"

That is the solution. Go to a previous Jquery.

Comment: I had jQuery 1.8.3 with no problems. I upgraded to 1.9 to appease some other plugins (and because 1.8.3 is 5 years old) and it gave me this error. So I believe your answer is on the right track. There has to be a workaround for later jQuery versions though...