# ASP.NET MVC: JavaScript error when starting index.cshtml instead of _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I start Home/index.cshtml (in Visual Studio 2013 by pressing F5) the website crashes with this error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

But when I start the website Shared/_Layout.cshtml it works fine.

**Home/index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">    
    <p id="greet-message" class="lead"></p>   
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // declare a reference to loginhub
            console.log("Logging in ...");

            // ***!!!*** HERE IT CRASHES! ***!!!***
            var login = $.connection.loginHub;

            //get's called when the user have been authenticated i.e. logged in
            login.client.greet = function (message) {
                $("#greet-message").html(message);
            };

            //start the hub
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                login.server.greet();
            });

        });
</script>
```

**Shared/_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

By default Shared/_Layout.cshtml loads Home/index.cshtml.

I thought it might be because the document wasn't ready so I changed the first function in index.cshtml to use `$( document ).ready(function()` but with no difference.

I used jQuery 1.10 but I downgraded it to 1.8.2 after this post but with no difference: [jquery validation error in Asp.net MVC - unable to get value of property 'call' : object is null or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749471/jquery-validation-error-in-asp-net-mvc-unable-to-get-value-of-property-call)

I am using `jquery.signalR-2.2.0` if that might cause some problems.

What is the difference from starting the website from index.cshtml instead of _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: What do you mean by "start website from _Layout.cshtml?" what URL are you typing into the browser?

Comment: Also, what does your `_ViewStart.cshtml` look like?

Comment: Hi Jasen, I open up index.cshtml or _Layout.cshtml in Visual Studio and I press F5. Visual Studio opens up website for me automatically.

Comment: I added _ViewStart.cshtml to the description.

Comment: I'd check the rendered page source to see that _Layout is inserted when you start Index. Then start removing script until it works so you can narrow down what's causing your error.